# Flutter Error - Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:lint'

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to sync `gradle` project after clicking "Open for editing in Android Studio".  I ran the command `gradlew build --warning-mode all` and found some specific things that went wrong. I tried adding the `lintOptions{}` but it didn't work. Any help please? Thank you in advance SO folks

```
* What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:lint'.
 > Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

 Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
 ...
 android {
     lintOptions {
         abortOnError false
     }
 }
 ...
 Errors found:

 C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler- 
 8.0.0+1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\ServiceManager.java:153: Error: Missing 
 permissions requ
 ired by BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled: android.permission.BLUETOOTH [MissingPermission]
      return bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler- 
 8.0.0+1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:54: Error: Call 
 requires API leve
 l R (current min is 16): android.os.Environment#isExternalStorageManager [NewApi]
          status = Environment.isExternalStorageManager()
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
   log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 3m 25s
    606 actionable tasks: 432 executed, 174 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the errors, it seems like there are two things missing,

1. You are using the `Bluetooth` api but failed to mention in the `AndroidManifest.xml` that you require the permission. To fix this, add the following line below your other permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml`,

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
   ```
2. You using the `Environment.isExternalStorageManager()` api which requires your minimum sdk version to be atleast `30`. Now there are two ways here,

   1. Either make changes in your app/build.gradle to this. Not a good idea.

      ```
      minSdkVersion 30
      ```
   2. Keep your min version but resort to other methods for accessing `isExternalStorageManager`.

Comment: i have added the bluetooth permisson and i am now just stuck at the second one. any idea on the second one? i've been looking all over the web but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: What exactly is your use case ?

Comment: i am trying to sign my apk from android studio for which i have to sync the gradle and apart from this nothing id causing error. my app is working perfectly fine but this is only occurring when trying to sync gradle i.e when i click `Open for editing in AS` in `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the error is a bit misleading when it mentions `(current min is 16)`.

The thing here is that the `permission_handler` plugin (starting from version 7.0.0) supports the`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission which requires Android API 30. This means your App should also compile against Android API 30, otherwise it will not recognise the new SDK methods (in this case `Environment.isExternalStorageManager()`).

To do this you simply update the `compileSdkVersion` in the `android/app/build.gradle` file to `30`:

```
compileSdkVersion: 30
```

For a complete example please refer to the `build.gradle` file of the permission_handler example App: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/example/android/app/build.gradle

Note that your App will still run fine on older Android versions. The permission_handler has a runtime check to ensure it will not try to call Android methods that are not supported on these older Android versions. This is only to instruct your compiler that is should compile against the Android API 30 SDK.

Of course, if you don't want to compile against the Android API 30 SDK, another option would be to downgrade permission_handler and use version 6.1.3.

Comment: so the `compileSdkVersion` is already set to 30 and so is the `targetSdkVersion`. and it's all the same. `BUILD FAILED` i don't know why but it seems like i need to add something in a certain java file   but i might be wrong as i haven't made this package but it just don't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I change  permission_handler 6.1.1 to permission_handler 8.3.0 and worked